# Ajax Firefox. Async on = Fails on all browsers. Async off = Works on GC, fails on FF and IE

Tags: html, ajax, browser

I know there are lots of these but all the pages i've seen are because they make there code all complicated and have lots of features. My code is very basic and is basically straight from the book. There nothing fancy. yet it fails? People tell me to use async on then it fails on every browser (Status = 0) when I run it with async off it works 100% fine on google chrome, but with FF it flickers the error code but still changes the width of the progress bar. IE doesen't work at all with it On

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/eGZFQvDK

Answer (score 1):

I didn't take the time to read your whole code, but I was recently using ajax with a form and had to set async to false (not 0) to get it to work the way I needed it to. Try that. With async set to true, my form was submitted prior to the completion of the AJAX script.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I just found something important... I was going threw the inspect element thing on firefox and came across this error when trying to use the script : 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/progressbar.php?progress_key=4f4a6b71bdc36. Origin http://www.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
java.js:54Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

So it sounds like a access issue. This is my first time seeing this error and hopefully my last :D